# Logitech MX Master is lagging in Ubuntu, but not in OS X or Windows

Tags: 18.04, mouse, bluetooth, logitech

I recently purchased a Logitech MX Master 2S, and have found that there is some mouse lag (input lag issues, and stuttering) on Ubuntu 18.04. I tried it on Windows and OS X to make sure that it wasn't a problem with the mouse, and it worked smoothly with no issues on both.

I tried installing [solaar](https://pwr.github.io/Solaar/), but I am having issues opening it due to a [bug](https://github.com/pwr/Solaar/commit/e1eee2e078ae986bb2e0947ce5a0ddca888a23ba) that is supposedly fixed according to the github repo.

I am currently using the unifying receiver as I am not able to connect through bluetooth because when I try to pair, I get the error:

```
Setting up 'MX Master 2S' Failed
```

Let me if you guys know anything I could do.

EDIT: I fixed the bluetooth, but not the lag issues from the unifying receiver. For the bluetooth fix, I switched the mouse to another profile and configured the bluetooth on that new one.

Comment: But you have no lag with bluetooth, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this issue of a glitching mouse during usage. The mouse was connected via the Unify-dongle and it had connections problems leading to occasional reconnections when the dongle was placed near another used USB3 port. I stumbled over [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/buildapc/comments/7ouumm/usb_30_with_logitech_unify_receiver_causing/) which explained that there was an issue with leaking USB3 frequencies interfering with the unify-dongle. **My solution was simply to move the dongle further away from those leaking usb ports**. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've connected mouse via provided unifying reveiver with help of this tool https://github.com/pwr-Solaar/Solaar.
It works without any lagging then.

Answer (score 0):

For Logitech items a lot helps [Solaar](https://github.com/pwr-Solaar/Solaar),

```
sudo apt install solaar
```

after successful installation unplug and plug receiver and

```
solaar --window=show
```

your receiver should be available in GUI. For me all laggs disappear even it fixed proper battery charge show